# Why has a moderator deleted this very good and informative post?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderators, vote-to-undelete

What's wrong with the following post? It's the most informative one among the other answers.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55554080/1841194

I tried to vote to undelete it but it says that:

> A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted

Comment: I'm going to guess it was plagiarized from [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/linux-nm-command/) and that has something to do with it.

Comment: That post had only one upvote, so arguably not "very good".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you look more closely at that post you'll see  that the informative part already is available elsewhere on the internet: the answer is copied verbatim from https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/linux-nm-command/

The author of the answer copied the text from that link, and added an extra link to Wikipedia. Later on they added some example output linked to a gist page they had made. Nothing in that post actually addresses the question asked; the part in that linked post that *would* have answered the stated question was not copied, ironically.

I deleted the answer because it was not their own work, it was [plagiarised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do). I usually leave a quick comment on such posts with the reason why I deleted it, but as I had a large number to process I didn't in this case.

It can only be un-deleted if the author replaced the content with original text, written by themselves, and at most [quotes from external sources to support their own work](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Copying small sections of external resources is fine, if you properly attribute those sections and mark them up clearly, and if it doesn't form the whole of the answer.

Comment: *"I usually leave a quick comment on such posts with the reason why I deleted it, but as I had a large number to process I didn't in this case."* - alas, this doesn't seems to have truly saved you any time, since you then wound up explaining yourself here.

Comment: @MarkAmery: I'll reconsider if this becomes a regular occurrence. I really am not going to got revisit hundreds of posts.

Comment: And this is why plagiarism is so much work even for mods.